# Nativescript+Angular: iOS emulator firing tap event multiple times

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

When I run the following piece of code on my iOS emulator, the `onTap()` method is called twice.  The exact same code run on my physical iPhone the `onTap()` is only called once.  I know its the same code because `tns run ios` deploys to both simultaneously.

**home.component.html**:

```
<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" visability="collapsed"></ActionBar>

<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
    <Button (tap)="onTap($event)" class="fas btn btn-primary" text="Test"></Button>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

**home.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  counter = 0;
  constructor(private _page: Page) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._page.actionBarHidden = true;
  }

  onTap(args) {
    this.counter++;
    console.log('Tapped ' + this.counter + ' times!');
  }
}
```

When I press button on emulator I get (note counter is not incremented):

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/home/home.component.js:15:20: Tapped 1 times!
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/home/home.component.js:15:20: Tapped 1 times!
```

Same code, on physical iPhone I get:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/home/home.component.js:15:20: Tapped 1 times!
```

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: '~/app/test/test.module#TestModule',
    data: {
      title: 'Test'
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.1.0",
    "nativescript-ngx-fonticon": "~4.2.0",
    "nativescript-orientation": "~2.2.1",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "~2.2.6",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "~3.11.1",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "~5.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.5.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript": "~5.1.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.19.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0"
  },
```

Things I've tried:

- Delete app from emulator
- Delete `hooks`,`node_modules`,`platforms` and re-run `tns run ios`
- Created a similar [app in the playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=t9CUK1), and everything is fine (`onTap()` is only called once on the emulator).

Any ideas?

Comment: I downloaded the project from Playground, it seems to work fine on my end. With iPhone XR Simulator it prints the log only once per tap.

Comment: Yup, I made that sample project to just show what my code looked like. The sample project works fine for me as well.  I've updated my Q to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It was something with filewatcher. Two instances of it running was deploying the same app 2x on device.  Hard to explain.

I `Hardware > Erase all content and settings..`, killed my terminal, opened a new one and ran `tns run ios`.